# Javascript simple UDF

Tags: javascript

I'm now developing one JS UDF which seems following coding.

```
<script>
<!-- 
 function alertmsg()
 {
  alert("Hello World");
 }
 for(p=1; p <= 2; p++)
 {
  alertmsg();
 }
 -->
</script>
```

Normally, Alert Msg will be came out two times because of loop count is 2. What I want is Alert Msg will be came out only one time even loop count is 3. Any idea will be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Regardless of what your server-side language is, this is a JavaScript function.  In CF, the term "UDF" is typically reserved for ColdFusion functions, which are server-side only.

Comment: I agree Ben Doom, in javascript it is referred to as a function. But remember that t-sql also uses the term UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to execute the piece of code once in the loop? Do something like this:

```
var executed = false;
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
   if (!executed) {
      alertmsg();
      executed = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps this?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        function alertmsg() {
            alert("Hello World");
        }

        for (var p = 0; p < 3; p++) {

            if (p == 2) {
                alertmsg();
            }

        }

    </script>
```